# Creating a tree graph in R that maps frequency of paths

Tags: r, tree

I struggled titling this post, but hopefully the example and explanation below will help. I would like to create a tree graph that shows the frequency of different "paths" in my data. I have the following dataframe:

```
zed = data.frame(
  node1 = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A"),
  node2 = c("A", "B", "A", "B", "A", "B", "A", "B"),
  node3 = c("B", "C", "D", "D", "C", "D", "C", "C"),
  node4 = c("C", "C", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "C"),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)
```

and I would like to create a graph in R that looks something along these lines (really rough sketch made quickly in excel):

[image]

Essentially, each row in the dataframe is a path. All paths start at "A", which is why "A" is the single top node, and then (in this example) they progress to B, C and D. Certain paths occur more frequently than others (A -> B -> C -> C shows up twice, whereas some other paths show up once), and I think I would like this reflected in the size of the nodes.

I am not sure if i should reformat my data for this, and also which R graphing library is best for this. Happy to add more context - any help is appreciated!!

Comment: What you are asking seems unclear to me. It seems like you are asking for the size of the node to reflect the frequency of the paths, but most nodes are involved in multiple paths.so this size would have to reflect multiple frequencies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The advice I'm going to give is for the `igraph` package:

To create a graph from a data frame your data has to be in long format where the first two columns represents the nodes links are coming from (the first column) and where the links are going to (the second column). Also, the names of the nodes have to be unique, so an edge from 'A' to 'A' is simply a node pointing to itself. Your data has different nodes named 'A'. Using your data, you will need to do something like this:

```
zed$node1 <- paste0(zed$node1, '_1')
zed$node2 <- paste0(zed$node2, '_2')
zed$node3 <- paste0(zed$node3, '_3_', 1:nrow(zed))
zed$node4 <- paste0(zed$node4, '_4_', 1:nrow(zed))

edgelist <- rbind(
  as.matrix(zed[c('node1', 'node2')]),
  as.matrix(zed[c('node2', 'node3')]),
  as.matrix(zed[c('node3', 'node4')])
)
```

Which will give you:

[image: edgelist]

To plot it  you will need to do something like this:

```
library(igraph)
g <- graph_from_data_frame(edgelist)
plot(g, layout = layout_as_tree(g))
```

[image: tree layout]

If you want to learn more, then I highly recommend taking a look at Katya Ognyanova's tutorials: http://kateto.net/tutorials/

Answer (score 0):

I'm simply going to look into both iGraph and data.tree packages for this and see which package works better for making this graph of mine.

Will try to remember to post an update here if I am successful.